# Convert .xls/.xlsx spreadsheets to multiple .csv's based on a list

Tags: command-line, csv, xls

I need to convert all sheets of a single .xls/.xlsx file to a .csv. This will be done on all .xls files in all directories and sub-directories (recursively).

**Step 1**: Get the sheetnames of all .xls into a .csv using:

```
for file in $(find . -name '*.xls' -o -name '*.xlsx');do in2csv -n "$file" > ${file%.xls}-sheetnames-list.csv; done
```

`filename-sheetnames-list.csv` can act as a list:

```
sheetname1
sheetname2
sheetname3
```

**Step 2** : 
The code for converting a specific sheet into a .csv using in2csv is:

```
in2csv --sheet "SHEETNAME" filename.xls > filename-SHEETNAME.csv
```

How can I get every sheetname in a .xls/x and write every sheet separately  for all directories containing a .xls/x ?

`in2csv --write-sheets "-" filename.xls > filename-sheet1.csv filename-sheet2.csv ....` gives output only on sheet1.csv, not sure how to get all sheets from this.

Comment: Why not just `find` every `.xls{,x}` and loop over every sheet using `-exec`?

Comment: @glennjackman this is perfectly on topic here, just as it would be on [unix.se].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just put a loop inside another loop.

To avoid errors, don't use `for` with `find` results.

```bash
while IFS= read -r file; do
    while IFS= read -r sheet; do
        in2csv --sheet "$sheet" "$file" > "${file%.*}-${sheet}.csv"
    done < <(in2csv -n "$file")
done < <(find . -name '*.xls' -o -name '*.xlsx')
```

Comment: @muru ah crap. You're absolutely right. I'd tested in an environment where the IFS had already been changed so of course it propagated downwards. *Idiot*. Thanks, edit reverted.

Comment: @RoVo the first option works fine. The second one however gives me no output or error. I am unsure why; for a single `.xls` `in2csv --write-sheets "-" filename.xls > sheetname.csv` gives only the first sheet. I don't know what additional info to add to write all sheets. That shall give us clues to correct your code.

Comment: did you update to that version 1.0.2 ? `pip install csvkit -U`. I think the way it works is not what you like, with the simple skript from 1st option you have more ways to control the output and the filenames etc.

Comment: still doesn't work with the update, and yes I'd prefer using a list than `--write-sheets`  Maybe you can set this alternative option as another answer... I will accept the first option as the answer then. Thanks @RoVo

Comment: Maybe generally a good idea to have alternative options in another answer. Thanks, glad that I could help.

Answer (score 7):

Skipping find and using bash:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar  # enable recursive globbing
for f in **/*.xls{,x}  # for files ending in .xls or .xlsx
do
    in2csv -n "$f" |   # get the sheetnames
      xargs -I {} bash -c 'in2csv --sheet "$2" "$1" > "${1%.*}"-"$2".csv' _ "$f" {} # {} will be replaced with the sheetname
done
```

Comment: this script looks elegant but its output is `filename-{}.csv` containing no data. I'm a novice and can't seem to find the error by editing the script and reading up. Some help?

Comment: @ChintanSheth my bad, I'd forgotten the redirection would be outside `xargs`. Corrected, not as elegant now.

Comment: `xargs` and `>` is evil :-P. That's why I prefer another loop, it's less error prone.

Comment: @RoVo I'd have usually gone for another loop too, just wanted to show another method here.

Comment: This works now, however slightly slower than @RoVo answer.

Answer (score 3):

[csvkit version > 1.0.2](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/scripts/in2csv.html) has a builtin function to write all sheets:

```
--write-sheets: WRITE_SHEETS
                      The names of the Excel sheets to write to files, or
                      "-" to write all sheets.
```

So you could try the following:

```
find . -name '*.xls' -o -name '*.xlsx' -exec in2csv --write-sheets "-" {} \;
```

Note:

This seems not to work 100% as expected. But worth a try and as this is the first version with that option maybe in future versions the implementation is better/easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Gnumeric`:

```
ssconvert -S filename.xlsx filename.csv
```

to get one `csv` file per sheet.