# How to split an ODS spreadsheet file into csv files per sheet on the terminal?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, csv, xls

I would like to split a spreadsheet (ods or xlsx) into multiple csv files, one for each sheet in the spreadsheet.

I would like to do this without launching a graphical app and preferably in a one liner.

Any ideas?

Though the linked duplicate provides a possible solution in one of the answers (not in the accepted one) and was helpful. The solution does not work with ODS files as I requested, and I consider the question to be sufficiently different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert .xls/.xlsx spreadsheets to multiple .csv's based on a list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973534/convert-xls-xlsx-spreadsheets-to-multiple-csvs-based-on-a-list)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, `libreoffice` can convert documents from a script (i.e. in headless mode without opening a GUI). To convert any spreadsheet format to CSV, its simplest form  would look like e.g.

```
libreoffice --convert-to csv PATH/TO/YOUR.ODS
```

However, this just takes the first sheet of your document and converts that, ignoring all others. It also lacks an option to select the sheet to convert, sadly.

---

So we're going to need an external tool, like [xlsx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv). It's an open source Python (both 2 and 3) script that converts XLSX files to CSV, and supports extracting all sheets into separate files.

Ubuntu already comes with Python installed, but maybe you need to install `pip` first, its package manager. I'm going for Python 3, but you could change all commands below to run it with 2 as well:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Then you can install `xlsx2csv` with `pip3` into your user's package directory, using

```
pip3 install --user xlsx2csv
```

After that, the executable script can be found in `~/.local/bin/xlsx2csv`.

---

Now if you don't have it in XLSX format already, let's convert that ODS spreadsheet with `libreoffice`:

```
libreoffice --convert-to xlsx PATH/TO/YOUR.ods
```

Then we use `xlsx2csv` to extract all sheets. It will create a folder `OUTPUTFOLDER` and place all extracted `SHEETNAME.csv` in there:

```
~/.local/bin/xlsx2csv -a YOUR.xlsx OUTPUTFOLDER
```

Comment: apt-get install xlsx2csv already returns a package, any reason I should not try that?

Comment: Ok, I did us and and it works as you describe

Comment: @Bruni Good observation, I didn't realize it's in the repositories. However, as always, the Ubuntu package is quite outdated (version 0.20 from 2012 in the Ubuntu repos vs. version 0.7.3 (don't question that numbering scheme...) from 2017 as Python package on PyPI). I tested with the PyPI version, you might possibly run into already fixed bugs with the packaged version, don't know. Probably it works just as well most of the time. You can have a look at the [changelog](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv/blob/master/CHANGELOG).

Answer (score 4):

Using [`xls2csv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xls2csv.1.html) (to convert **.XLS**) tool of [`catdoc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/catdoc.1.html) package install `sudo apt install catdoc`:

```
xls2csv -b '
' EXCEL.xls | awk '{print >"sheet"NR}' RS='\n\n'
```

This `xls2csv -b '
' EXCEL.xls` reads MS-Excel file and puts its content as comma-separated data on standard output and with `-b STRING` we are telling sheets to delimited with what characters (or string; which we defined a actual newline here).

---

Use [`xlsx2csv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xlsx2csv.1.html) (to convert **.XLSX**); install `sudo apt install xlsx2csv`:

```
xlsx2csv -s 0 EXCEL.xlsx |
    awk '!/,/ { nextSheet++; next } { print >"sheet"nextSheet }'
```

The `-s 0` means print all sheets.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at

```
ssconvert -O 'separator=:: format=raw quoting-mode=never' -S x.ods  out%n.txt
```

\thanks{Bruni}

- `-O 'separator= format= ...'`is used to control the csv format details
- `-S` to create a different output file for each sheet

Comment: Strangely this did not work with the xlsx file I tried, and it converted only the last sheet when used with ods.

Comment: Undefined number format id '43'
Undefined number format id '41'
Undefined number format id '44'
Undefined number format id '42'
Unexpected element 'workbookProtection' in state : 
        workbook

Comment: It worked with the -S flag on the ods though, so +1

Comment: @Bruni, help me: could you please fix my incomplete answer? `ssconvert -O 'separator=:: format=raw quoting-mode=never' x.xlsx  -S 'out-%n.txt'`  ?

Comment: It works the way I modified your answer, though the naming schmeme of the result is suboptimal

Comment: @Bruni, if the output name is ` 'out-%n.txt'` or `'out-%n.txt'` it should include number or name of the sheet.

Comment: You are right. As I modified it now it works