# How to manipulate data in excel file using Linux terminal?

Tags: command-line, xls

I have an excel file I would like to extract the information in column 2  and only information in  square brackets and copy it to column 3 and then  delete whatever has been copied from column 3. using the terminal. How do I go about it ?

Below is my sample data.

[image: EXCEL SNIPPET OFMY DATA]

Expected output:

[image: Expected output]

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: If you allow programming as 'terminal manipulation', then have a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/457696/how-to-create-excel-xlsx-files-from-a-script

Comment: 20.04 LTS -  Ubuntu Terminal on windows 10 Operating System.

Comment: Not as such, check the expected out-put.

Comment: `secretary` shouldn't be in next line? and column3 in `and then delete whatever has been copied from column 3` should be then column2 based on expected output. also do you wish the output to be XLS? are you able to install tools mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/q/1042624/283843? have you tried them?

Comment: yes I have already installed them. The output should be in XLS.

Comment: when you want feedback something to a person add `@` followed by username like @αғsнιη, so user will be noticed for your comment.